# How do I authenticate my crash dumps to AWS Lambda?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda

I have an iOS Shopping App and want that the customers smartphones send Logs (when a crash happens for example) to an AWS Lambda function.

How can I avoid that other Apps than my own App can send Logs to this Lambda Function? I need some kind of authentification.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a great tutorial on something like this [here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/04/aws-lambda-authorizer/)

Basically you need to go through the process of setting up a Lambda authorizer, which is a multifaceted approach to authorization and can serve any need.

[The docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) are particularly verbose about this subject.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer!
But do you know if there is a possibility without an API Gateway between? I would like to save some costs by directly speaking to the Lambda but also have an authentication.